# For an integral domain, is a local subring of its field of fractions a localization of the original domain?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an integral domain, take K:=K(A) its field of fractions, and consider a local subring $B\subset K$ which contains $A.$ Is it necessarily true that $B$ is a localization of $A?$ Of course the only choice would be localizing $A$ at $S=B^*\cap A,$ but the condition of $B\subset K$ only guarantees that we may write $b\in B$ as $f/g$ for some $f,g\in A.$ I'm not sure how to guarantee I can choose $g$ to be a unit in $B,$ though the obvious potential counterexamples like $A=k[x^2,x^3]$ seem to work out.

If this doesn't hold in general, the specific case where I'm running into this is the following: let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be an integral scheme which is separated and of finite type over a field $k.$ Let $x_1,x_2\in X$ be two points such that the inclusion $\mathcal{O}_{x_1,X}\to K(X)$ of the local ring at $x_1$ factors through the inclusion $\mathcal{O}_{x_2,X}\to K(X).$ Is it true that $\mathcal{O}_{x_2,X}$ is a localization of $\mathcal{O}_{x_1,X}?$

Comment: Try. $A=k[x,y]\subset k[x,u]_{(x,u)}=B$ where. $u=y/x$ .

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample!